# Can't display character on IE 9

Tags: character-encoding, internet-explorer-9

This character ❯ doesn't appear correctly on IE 9, despite setting UTF-8 charset. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE often has serious difficulties in rendering a character when it does not exist in the fonts specified for an element or, in the absence of such specifications, in the browser’s default font.

The cure is to specify a list of fonts know to contain the character. For “❯” U+276F HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT (a rather special character), font coverage is very limited. Most computers have no font containing it. You can specify a font list like the following:

```
 font-family: DejaVu Sans, Symbola, Everson Mono, Dingbats, Segoe UI Symbol,
 Quivira, unifont;
```

But most users lack all of these fonts. You might consider using a downloadable font (web font) with `@font-face`. [DejaVu fonts](http://dejavu.sourceforge.net/), [Symbola](http://www.fonts2u.com/search.html?q=symbola), and [Quivira](http://www.quivira-font.com/) are free fonts, though they are rather large in file size.

More info: [Guide to using special characters in HTM](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Comment: I had the same problem. This helped a lot!:) Thanks so much for saving my day!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it could be a font-face issue. Choosing the wrong font face can prevent the character from displaying. Try a different Font.

**[(Guide to Encoding issues)](http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=384)**